# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in SBT revolver

Tags: java, scala, sbt

In general, [SBT revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) has worked well for me, but for some reason I've started seeing the following error over and over again: I'll be editing a particular class and will hit save and the following error message will pop up:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/path/to/class/ClassName.class' does not exist.
```

Is there a way to modify my `~/.sbtconfig` file to overcome this? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with SBT failing to launch due to missing class files. I think this happens when you delete a version of Java (i.e. downgrading from Java 1.8 to 1.7 or 1.6).

I know this is historical, but I've found a workaround:

On OS X Terminal, navigate your home directory `~` and create a new file using the command `vim .sbtconfig`. Paste the following:

`SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"`

Then save with `:wq` and restart sbt.

If you're still having this issue, please post an update and I'll try to give you some assistance.

Also, if you're not super Terminal-friendly, you can use a standard text editor to save the `.sbtconfig` file.